# Auto update shared Excel workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to refresh an Excel file every 30 seconds, it will be a read only file for one user. Nevertheless, the data will be filled by another user (in the same file). Is it possible to do that?

I searched a little and found [this explanation of auto updating files](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/program-excel-spreadsheet-autoupdate-40626.html), but when looking for the "Connection Properties", it's not available for me, almost every option is "greyed" or disabled.

[image: this screenshot]

I've tried to change the Trust Center but nothing happens.

Comment: Does your workbook contain external data? What connection do you use?

Comment: No it doesn't. And no, I do not have a connection. What I'm trying to do is to refresh a file that user A has on read-only, while user B is inserting data. Both in the same network.

Comment: The steps explained are for workbook with external data connection, for example using table from another worksheet, or connected to a MySQL database. It is greyed out because you don't have any connection to external workbook or database. You are looking for different thing, called **real time collaboration**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for **collaborating real time**.

[Co-authoring using Office 365](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_win10/co-authoring-comes-to-excel-on-windows-desktops/42ea1b8e-6601-4e53-aeb7-381e50387125?tm=1490716897997)

To use co-authoring, your users need to use supported platforms, which are:

1. Office 2016 Desktop **version 8017.1000**, currently *only* for **Fast Insider Ring** users
2. [Excel Online](https://office.live.com/start/Excel.aspx?WT.mc_id=O16_BingHP)
3. Excel for Android *or* Windows Mobile
4. Excel for iOS, currently *only* for **Insiders**

### How to use co-authoring using Office 2016 desktop

1. Update your **Office 2016** to **8017.1000** version. All other users who wish to use co-authoring also need to use one of supported platforms mentioned above. They can still collaborate *without* supported platforms, but the changes will **not** be seen real time.
2. Upload the file in Sharepoint Online, Onedrive, or Onedrive for Business.
3. Share the file with people you wish to collaborate with. They will receive an email with link to the file. When they click on the link, they will be redirected to Excel Online, opening the file.

**Note:** They already can co-author with Excel Online. If they wish to co-author with Windows desktop Office, click on **Edit Workbook > Edit in Excel**

That's it! You're set!
When you co-authoring with someone, there will be pictures (or photos) of people co-authoring the file.

[image: Co-authoring]

The changes are updated in a few seconds, and is made available for everyone by [Autosave feature](https://support.office.com/article/6d6bd723-ebfd-4e40-b5f6-ae6e8088f7a5), shown in upper-left corner.

You'll know what part they are currently editing by colored selection. Hovering over colored selection will reveal who is editing that part. Clicking on someone's picture will jump you to the part they are currently editing.

Your selection will **always** be green, just like everyone else selection is green in their own device.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, I think I'll install an auto-refresh widget in the web browser, thank you very much!